# Python list splicing for 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, multidimensional-array

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
matrix[3][1:] = matrix[3][0:-1]
print(matrix)
```

gives the following output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 13, 14, 15]]
```

But:

```
rows = 3
k = 0
matrix[rows-k][1+k:-k] = matrix[rows-k][k:-1-k]
print(matrix)
```

gives the following output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 13, 14, 15, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Can someone please explain to me what's going on?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you insert rows = 3 and k = 0:

```
matrix[3][1:0] = matrix[3][0:-1]
```

And it is **not the same** like your second line:

```
matrix[3][1:] = matrix[3][0:-1]
```

Added.

In first example you insert some data from **1. position to the end**:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a[1:] = [100, 200, 300]
print(a)
OUTPUT: [1, 100, 200, 300]
```

In the second case you insert a value **between the 0. and 1. position**:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a[1:0] = [100, 200, 300]
print(a)
OUTPUT: [1,100, 200, 300, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: "In the second case you insert a value between the 0. and 1. position" This statement is not right. a[1:0] returns an empty slice. Try printing this a[1:0] in the shell and you won't get the value b/w 0-1

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

This happens because

```py
matrix[rows-k][1+k:-k] = matrix[rows-k][k:-1-k]
```

is equivalent to

```py
matrix[3][1:0] = matrix[3][0:-1]
```

which is equivalent to

```py
matrix[3][1:1] = matrix[3][0:-1]
```

So when you do `matrix[3][1:0]` => `matrix[index][start:stop:None]`

Your start value is 1, which is more than your stop value of 0. In case of start >= stop Python sets `stop = start` and returns an empty slice.

You can check the value of matrix[3][1:1] which is an empty slice like matrix[3][1:0]

```py
>>> matrix[3][1:0]
[]
>>> matrix[3][1:1]
[]
```

Read more: Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

> If i is greater than or equal to j, the slice is empty